# Why are moderators silent?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I got flagged and have flagged others before. Moderators review and then nothing. I get no explanation regarding the resolution. I don't even get a notification per se. Just however long it takes me to notice a change in reputation points. It takes time to present an explanation, but the alternative is for nothing to change(?). If I don't know what I did wrong, what's to prevent me/others from repeating it? Ignoring the fact that it's only proper/logical to explain any disciplining action.

Then again, it shouldn't take that much time to explain. If we have radio buttons for flags, moderators can easily have similar when reviewing that links to the particular article and section under rules for the user to read.

And what if I don't think I did anything wrong or disagree with the explanation? Is there an appeal process?

Doesn't the power to moderate without explanation resembles tyranny? (Not that I expect Stack Overflow to be a democracy. It is still a web presence that needs to generate revenue.)

Comment: You can review your own flags on your profile. Users who are flagged don't get notifications unless it's a sever enough offense. Sometimes things like comments aren't a problem other than they are just obsolete.

Comment: Thanks. So what determines `severe`? So it's ok to repeat non severe offenses? Edit: I guess I am just asking for more transparency/why it's not already in place. Edit2: gonna start my weekend. You all have a good one^^

Comment: I think your question is not really answerable as written.  Different types of flags are handled in different ways, some by elected moderators, some by the regular users in the community with specific privileges.  Do you have some examples of the types of flags you raised that you are more interested in understanding?  Similarly, you mention flags raised against you.  No one really knows when a flag is raised against one of their posts, so you may be mistaking normal review actions for "flags".

Answer (score 12):

To quote [Jeff Atwood](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/618324806937657344):

> "Don't make a show, technically or socially, of punishing/banning someone unless you want your community to be about showy punishments."

When possible, moderators try not to make a spectacle out of moderation actions. Upon encountering problematic behavior, our goals are to first stop any further harm from being done to the site, and then to correct this behavior. If there's any hope for someone, we attempt to educate and reform them, and have found that this is most likely to succeed when someone isn't the subject of harsh penalties or public humiliation.

[Responses to all of your flags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4971065) are found in the Impact box within your profile. To your comment

> If we have radio buttons for flags, moderators can easily have similar when reviewing that links to the particular article and section under rules for the user to read.

We do have a standard list of radio-button responses when declining flags, and can write custom messages for both helpful flags and declined ones where necessary. Again, we most likely won't discuss with the flagger any actions we are taking to follow up about bad behavior. Sometimes you can see the public impacts of this from lost reputation due to invalidated votes or a temporary account suspension, but it's not something we announce.

For example, for the last user you flagged, the question was already taken care of by the time we got there and saw no indication of ongoing bad behavior after that. There was nothing more to be said, so we marked your flag as helpful and moved on.

All actions by moderators can be publicly challenged on Meta and elsewhere, or privately done so by contacting Stack Exchange directly. I can tell you from experience that the community is not afraid to confront us, and when we do make a mistake it is very quickly pointed out. We're elected, and if one of us went squarely against the wishes of the community at large I don't think that would go very well.

Comment: From the downvotes, it's clear that SO isn't interested in this discourse or maybe I communicated myself poorly. Regardless, I feel I owe you at least a comment for your generous wall of text. Good day.

Answer (score 9):

I can only assume you're making this post because of a flag you raised that was rightfully declined.

Put simply though, moderators do not inform the flaggers of the outcome of what we look in to.

Comment: Surely you have time for explanations and appeals of every flag you process. 

Comment: @BilltheLizard luv you long time too Bill :p